# Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported - WHERE/HOW?

Tags: sudo, logs, privileges

When a user not in sudoers tries to elevate privileges to root (in Ubuntu 18.04 for example) the OS displays this alert: "Username is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported".

Now, where can the admin see this report? How can admins detect an invalid `sudo` attempt?

I'm specifically interested in CentOS 7.

Comment: In their email.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, I tried to check in /var/mail but it's empty

Comment: That's not where mail is kept.

Comment: I don't think so @StephenKitt, I'm asking for a CentOS 7 OS. Meanwhile Ubuntu save this notification into "/var/log/auth.log", I can't find where CentOS save this event.

Comment: Sorry @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams,can you tell me where in CentOS 7 this information is stored? Thank you.

Comment: @Roberto you might have missed this important part: “Depending on how `sudo` is configured on your system”. The linked question isn’t Ubuntu-specific, although I note you did appear to ask about Ubuntu in your question.

Comment: Here's the answer: https://xkcd.com/838/

Comment: @dr01, the final proof that Santa exists! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On CentOS 7 (since that’s apparently what you’re really interested in), such incidents are reported in the journal; run `journalctl -xe` as root and you’ll see lines such as

```
guest : user NOT in sudoers
```

when a user runs `sudo` without being allowed to, or

```
guest : 3 incorrect password attempts
```

when a user gets their password wrong too many times (with other information as usual in log messages).